# Inverse matrix for a matrix with sinus and cosinus functions

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have this matrix A:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x \end{array}\right)$$

and I need to create an inverse matrix for this matrix A. The sinus and cosinus functions in there makes me confused, I don't know how to start and proceed.
To count a determinant from this matrix is kinda easy, but how to count an inverse matrix to this?

Thank you

Comment: Do the same thing you would do to find the inverse of any matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Or notice this is a rotation matrix... Just rotate in the other direction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a matrix where
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)
$$
then inverse of $M$  is
$$
M^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\left(\begin{array}{cc} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{array}\right)
$$
Similarly
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x \end{array}\right)
$$
then inverse of $A$  is
\begin{align}
A^{-1}&=\frac{1}{(\cos x)(\cos x)-(-\sin x)(\sin x)}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x \end{array}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x \end{array}\right)\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x \end{array}\right)
\end{align}
where $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, V-Moy. Just a question - this procedure is suitable only for matrixes 2x2? How would be the solution, if there would be a similar matrix, but the dimensions would be 3x3?

Comment: @user984621 You're right. This is only for $2\times2$ matrix. For $n\times n$ matrix, where $n>2$, you can learn from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html).

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Your matrix represents an anti-clockwise rotation about the origin, through $x$-radians.

Geometrically, what is the inverse of that transformation?

Clockwise rotations are given by negative angles.

If you insist upon findind the inverse algebraically, note that $\det = \cos^2x + \sin^2x \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is a rotation by angle $x$. Therefore the inverse is the rotation by the angle $-x$, which has the same form except you just substitute $-x$ for $x$. Using $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$ and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x) = - \sin(x)$ you can numerically verify this matrix gives the inverse.